# Add css class after the elements are created from a JS script

Tags: jquery

I have a div

```
 <div id="form"/>
```

Some JS is building up a form from this div.

The result looks like

```
 <div id="form"> 
     <fieldset>
             ..inputs
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
             ..inputs
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
             ..inputs
     </fieldset> 
 </div>
```

Once the form has been build up I need to run this scripts

```
$(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form");
$(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").removeClass("txt_textarea");
```

The problem is when I put these scripts behind to code which is building up the form, the fieldset has not been build yet.

I cannot add attach a class to the fieldset in the JS code,which is building up the form.

Is there any way to wait until the form is build up and then add and remove the css ?

This isn't working

```
  $(function(){
        var form = new Form("@Model.Name");
        form.AdditionalConfigUrlParams += "isshow=uloha"
        form.Create(@Html.Raw(Model.Data));

        $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form");
        $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").removeClass("dhxlist_txt_textarea");

    });
```

Comment: can we see the buildup and what you have tried please

Answer (score 1):

if your form creator had as a complete event you could put it in there otherwise you might want to look at [livequery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)

```
    $('form').livequery(function() {
        $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form");
         $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").removeClass("txt_textarea");
   }
```

Comment: Since 1.5 there's a new function when http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ Could this func help me ?

Comment: I have no experience with .when function you'd have to look into that but from what I've read I don't think that will work

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form");
    $(":input","fieldset:eq(2)").removeClass("txt_textarea");
});
```

Comment: i think the problem is in your selectors i suggest to see the other answers it appears that my answer in not 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors are not right. It should be:

```
$(":input, fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form");// removed quotes between selectors
$(":input, fieldset:eq(2)").removeClass("txt_textarea");// same here
```

Also this will only select last fieldset.

Comment: With your modification the selectors stoped working as they should.

Comment: Well, well, how is it possible that they stopped working when they did not worked at all? Look here http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ Maybe if you are a bit more clear about what you want you will get some better answers.

Comment: I have a tool named firebuq where is a JS console, have you heard about it ? :-) And those selectors shouldn't be multiple selectors, but a context selector. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Ok. You are just using it in strange way. Context is used when it is easier to pass it that way than as regular selector. In your case you could use $('fieldset:eq(2) :input') which is more readable. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

u can check that form has been created or not

```
var formReady=form.create(@Html.Raw(Model.Data); // IDK what plugin you r using to create a form
if(formReady) {
 $(":input,fieldset:eq(2)").addClass("readonly-form").removeClass("dhxlist_txt_textarea");
}
```

or try @mcgrailm method